# Array Syntax Error For Assignments with Braces

Tags: java, arrays

EDIT: Sorry about ellipsis that's not what I actually have.

For declaring an array I have something like:

```
package hearts;

public class pack
{
    String[] values = {"0", "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "T", "J", "Q", "K"};
    String[] suits = {"Hearts", "Spades", "Diamonds", "Clubs"}; 

    card[] deck = new card[52]; 

    for (int i = 1; i < 14; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<4; j++)
        {
            deck[j*13 + i] = new card(suits[j], values[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

And it keeps telling me Syntax error on token ";", { expected. Does anyone have any ideas what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Post your complete code.

Comment: @Matt your source looks ok (after edit). Are you sure this is the line that causes the problems ?

Comment: This line of code is correct. I think you have an error in the code segment before/after this line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have put instructions at the class level. Declare a method and put your instructions there, for example:

```
public class pack
{
    String[] values = {"0", "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "T", "J", "Q", "K"};
    String[] suits = {"Hearts", "Spades", "Diamonds", "Clubs"}; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        card[] deck = new card[52]; 

        for (int i = 1; i < 14; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j<4; j++)
            {
                deck[j*13 + i] = new card(suits[j], values[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you may put the code into any other method, not necessarily `main` and not necessarily `static`.

Answer (score 0):

Well of course the compiler complains about the syntax. What's with the `...` there ?